# Android studio gradle.build problems while lunching the app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

Completely I was created an Android app. Now this app on playstore. Problem is, some users are review that they can't open this app. This app will stopped after splash. but my phone and android emulator working fine. but while I will change the gradle build version it results the users reviews. it's really stopped. now i want to solve this problems and so tried. please explain me how to solve this error issue.?

my first gradle file working. but second gradle file fetching this problem.

> first

```
gradle.build
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.gurujibd.test"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile files('libs/awais.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(':dBPullToRefresh')
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

> 2nd gradle

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.gurujibd.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    implementation files('libs/awais.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation project(':dBPullToRefresh')
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
}
```

dBPullToRefresh
gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 4
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.eA(SourceFile:85)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:23)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.l.get(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:49)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4)
```

Comment: do you have logs ?

Comment: @SotirisS.Magionas please see the logcat error

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following and tell me if this resolved the issue.

First, change

```
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
```

Then, change these lines of code

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-beta01'
```

with these lines of code

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.+'
```

Now press ***Sync Now*** and run your code.

PS: Android Studio might prompt you to download certain packages if they are not readily available, just allow it to do so.

Comment: not working... same problem. splash activity working. but while finishing loading splash then the app will be stopped. but my first graddle file working. my first api level is 24. but requirement is 26. so i want to build it in 28. while using your instructions, it's working like my 2nd gradle. my 2nd gradle and your instructions is same to work. but not fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the problem is from Gradle? use crash reporters like [fabric.io](http://fabric.io)